# symbolic solution to trig equation for a variable

Tags: trigonometry, symbolic-computation

Is it possible to solve the following singular transcendental equation in $a$ for the variable $a$? Any symbolic solution will do.

$$\sqrt{s^2 - v^2} = 2a \, \sinh \left( \frac{h}{2a} \right)\,\,\,$$

If so, I'd like to see the resulting equation.

Even given additional computation time, [Wolfram Alpha can't](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20sqrt(s%5E2%20-%20v%5E2)%20%3D%202a%20sinh(%20h%2F(2a)%20)%20for%20a).

More about the equation on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Determining_parameters

Comment: These tags and titles are confusing. Do you want a numerical solution or a symbolic solution?

Comment: @Arkamis [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Determining_parameters) "This is a transcendental equation in a and must be solved numerically", but if a symbolic solution exists, that's even better.

Comment: A numerical solution is a numerical approximation to a solution to an arbitrary degree of precision. A symbolic solution is an exact solution coded in mathematical symbols. If an equation must be solved numerically, you cannot expect a solution in terms of your parameters; accordingly, you must prescribe some values for $s, v, h$. Being transcendental does not mean symbolically unsolvable; however, it means it is generally unlikely for symbolic solutions in terms of elementary functions to exist.

Comment: @Arkamis Because I don't have a given s,v, and h, I am wanting a symbolic solution. I don't mind the use of non-elementary functions at all in your solution. Question edited to reflect this.

Comment: I highly doubt one exists.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of $a\sinh(A/a)=B$ does not possess a closed form expression. Neither does that of the much simpler $a\sinh a=C$, for that matter. **However**, assuming a very small value for *a*, we can then easily express the approximate solution in terms of [*Lambert's W function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), since one of the two exponential terms of $\sinh(A/a)$ will be approximately $0$, yielding $\exp(A/a)\approx B/a$, which in its turn gives $a=-A/W(-A/B)$, where $A=h/2$, and $B=\tfrac12\sqrt{s^2-v^2}$. **But if** *a* were to be large instead of small, we'd have $\sinh(A/a)\approx A/a+\tfrac16(A/a)^3$, which yields a quadratic equation in *a*, whose roots are $a=\pm A\Big/\!\sqrt{6~(B/A-1)}$. I'm afraid that, analytically, this is as good as it gets.